# CSS Horizontal Sub Menu

Tags: css, submenu

basically i have a side by side horizontal menu as you can see here: http://www.supplements-today.co.uk/walnutgarth3/availability.php

what im trying to do is make it so that 'onhover' there is a sub menu that drops down on certain selections, for example 'pictures'. my attempt at this can be seen here: http://www.supplements-today.co.uk/walnutgarth3/

now i have got the drop down part to work, but it screws up my style of the rest of the menu as you can see. for me the problem is that the '

anyone know what my problem is here? you can see my menu code in pagesource but my css so far to go with it is:

```
#tier1 div{ display:none; }

#tier1{
position: relative;
left: 70px;
height: 20px;

}

#tier2{
position: relative;
display: block;


}
```

i kno thats empty, but iv played around with loads of different ways and cant seem to get it to work. any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using some JQuery menu plugin. JQuery is used widely and has plenty of examples over internet to browse for menus.
One of the examples can be found [here.](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu/)

Comment: ok thanks for the response, its worked almost perfectly. iv slightly changed the code to make it display block inline instead but im just wondeing - how do i get it so that the drop down part of the menu starts from the left hand side (more under the 'home') coz as you can see it goes off the pgae on the right hand side. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this html code may be you want like this format:

```
        <html>
        <head>
        <style>
        #pcm{display:none;}
        ul.cssMenu ul{display:none}
        ul.cssMenu li:hover>ul{display:block}
        ul.cssMenu ul{position: absolute;left:-1px;top:98%;}
        ul.cssMenu ul ul{position: absolute;left:98%;top:-2px;}
        ul.cssMenu,ul.cssMenu ul {
            margin:0px;
            list-style:none;
            padding:0px 1px 1px 0px;
            background-color:#A5A5A5;
            background-repeat:repeat;
            border-color:#A6A6A6;
            border-width:0px;
            border-style:solid;
        }
        ul.cssMenu table {border-collapse:collapse}ul.cssMenu {
            display:block;
            zoom:1;
            float: left;
        }
        ul.cssMenu ul{
            width:150px;
        }
        ul.cssMenu li{
            display:block;
            margin:1px 0px 0px 1px;
            font-size:0px;
        }
        ul.cssMenu a:active, ul.cssMenu a:focus {
        outline-style:none;
        }
        ul.cssMenu a, ul.cssMenu li.dis a:hover, ul.cssMenu li.sep a:hover {
            display:block;
            vertical-align:middle;
            background-color:#FFFFFF;
            border-width:0px;
            border-color:#787878;
            border-style:solid;
            text-align:left;
            text-decoration:none;
            padding:5px;
            padding-left: 8px;
            padding-right: 8px;
            width:130px;
            font:normal 11px Arial;
            color: #000000;
            text-decoration:none;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        ul.cssMenu span{
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        ul.cssMenu li {
            float:left;
        }
        ul.cssMenu ul li {
            float:none;
        }
        ul.cssMenu ul a {
            text-align:left;
            white-space:nowrap;
        }
        ul.cssMenu li.sep{
            text-align:left;
            padding:0px;
            line-height:0;
            height:100%;
        }
        ul.cssMenu li.sep span{
            float:none; padding-right:0;
            height:100%;
            background-color:#424242;   background-image:none;}
        ul.cssMenu ul li.sep span{
            width:100%;
            height:3;
        }
        ul.cssMenu li:hover{
            position:relative;
        }
        ul.cssMenu li:hover>a{
            background-color:#5A5A5A;
            border-color:#4C99AB;
            border-style:solid;
            font:normal 11px Arial;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        ul.cssMenu li a:hover{
            position:relative;
            background-color:#5A5A5A;
            border-color:#4C99AB;
            border-style:solid;
            font:normal 11px Arial;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        ul.cssMenu li.dis a {
            color: #AAAAAA !important;
        }
        ul.cssMenu img {border: none;float:left;_float:none;margin-right:5px;width:16px;
        height:16px;
        }
        ul.cssMenu ul img {width:16px;
        height:16px;
        }
        ul.cssMenu img.over{display:none}
        ul.cssMenu li.dis a:hover img.over{display:none !important}
        ul.cssMenu li.dis a:hover img.def {display:inline !important}
        ul.cssMenu li:hover > a img.def  {display:none}
        ul.cssMenu li:hover > a img.over {display:inline}
        ul.cssMenu a:hover img.over,ul.cssMenu a:hover ul img.def,ul.cssMenu a:hover a:hover ul img.def,ul.cssMenu a:hover a:hover a:hover ul img.def,ul.cssMenu a:hover a:hover img.over,ul.cssMenu a:hover a:hover a:hover img.over,ul.cssMenu a:hover a:hover a:hover a:hover img.over{display:inline}
        ul.cssMenu a:hover img.def,ul.cssMenu a:hover ul img.over,ul.cssMenu a:hover a:hover ul img.over,ul.cssMenu a:hover a:hover a:hover ul img.over,ul.cssMenu a:hover a:hover img.def,ul.cssMenu a:hover a:hover a:hover img.def,ul.cssMenu a:hover a:hover a:hover a:hover img.def{display:none}
        ul.cssMenu a:hover ul,ul.cssMenu a:hover a:hover ul,ul.cssMenu a:hover a:hover a:hover ul{display:block}
        ul.cssMenu a:hover ul ul,ul.cssMenu a:hover a:hover ul ul{display:none}
        ul.cssMenu span{
            display:block;
            background-image:url(http://purecssmenu.com/ssc-data/templates/clear-2/images/arrv_blue_2.gif);
            background-position:right center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
           padding-right:8px;}
        ul.cssMenu li:hover>a>span{ background-image:url(http://purecssmenu.com/ssc-data/templates/clear-2/images/arrv_white_2.gif);
        }
        ul.cssMenu a:hover span{    _background-image:url(http://purecssmenu.com/ssc-data/templates/clear-2/images/arrv_white_2.gif)}
        ul.cssMenu ul span,ul.cssMenu a:hover table span{background-image:url(http://purecssmenu.com/ssc-data/templates/clear-2/images/arr_blue_2.gif)}
        ul.cssMenu ul li:hover > a span{    background-image:url(http://purecssmenu.com/ssc-data/templates/clear-2/images/arr_white_2.gif);}
        ul.cssMenu table a:hover span,ul.cssMenu table a:hover a:hover span,ul.cssMenu table a:hover a:hover a:hover span{background-image:url(http://purecssmenu.com/ssc-data/templates/clear-2/images/arr_white_2.gif)}
        ul.cssMenu table a:hover table span,ul.cssMenu table a:hover a:hover table span{background-image:url(http://purecssmenu.com/ssc-data/templates/clear-2/images/arr_blue_2.gif)}
        ul.cssMenu li a.cssMenui0{
        font:n;
        }
        ul.cssMenu li a.cssMenui0:hover{
        font:o;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <ul class="cssMenu cssMenum">
            <li class=" cssMenui0"><a class="  cssMenui0" href="#"><span>Data Transfer</span></a>
            <ul class=" cssMenum">
                <li class=" cssMenui"><a class="  cssMenui" href="#">Import From SPP Offline</a></li>
                <li class=" cssMenui"><a class="  cssMenui" href="#">Export to SPP Offline</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class=" cssMenui0"><a class="  cssMenui0" href="#"><span>Settings</span><!--[if gt IE 6]--></a>
            <ul class=" cssMenum">
                <li class=" cssMenui"><a class="  cssMenui" href="#">Leave Report Settings</a></li>
                <li class=" cssMenui"><a class="  cssMenui" href="#">Mail Server Settings</a></li>
                <ul class=" cssMenum">
                    <li class=" cssMenui"><a class="  cssMenui" href="#"><span>Windows OS</span></a>
                    <ul class=" cssMenum">
                        <li class=" cssMenui"><a class="  cssMenui" href="#">Internet Explorer</a></li>
                        <li class=" cssMenui"><a class="  cssMenui" href="#">Netscape Navigator</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class=" cssMenui"><a class="  cssMenui" href="#">MAC OS</a></li>
                    <li class=" cssMenui"><a class="  cssMenui" href="#">Unix/Linux OS</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=" cssMenui"><a class="  cssMenui" href="#">About Company</a></li>
                <li class=" cssMenui"><a class="  cssMenui" href="#">Flash News</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class=" cssMenui0"><a class="  cssMenui0" href="#"><span>Admin References</span></a>
            <ul class=" cssMenum">
                <li class=" cssMenui"><a class="  cssMenui" href="#">Change Password</a></li>
                <li class=" cssMenui"><a class="  cssMenui" href="#">Login History</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class=" cssMenui0"><a class="  cssMenui0" href="#"><span>User Details</span></a>
            <ul class=" cssMenum">
                <li class=" cssMenui"><a class="  cssMenui" href="#">User Master</a></li>
                <li class=" cssMenui"><a class="  cssMenui" href="#">Assign Employee to Sanction</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class=" cssMenui0"><a class="  cssMenui0" href="#"><span>Reports</span></a>
            <ul class=" cssMenum">
                <li class=" cssMenui"><a class="  cssMenui" href="#">Assigned Employees</a></li>
                <li class=" cssMenui"><a class="  cssMenui" href="#">Unassigned Employees</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </body>
        </html>
```